# Show key as value in datatable

Tags: javascript, datatable

Hi I'm currently having trouble with datatable. My datasource is object and I want every first key in the object displayed as value in datatable. Here is my code.

```
  var my_data = {
          "content": [
             {
               "data_v1": [{"id" : 1}]
             },
             {
               "data_v2": [{"id" : 2}]
             },
             {
               "data_v3": [{"id" : 3}]
             }
          ]
       };



     $(document).ready(function() {
          $('#example').DataTable( {
              data:my_data,
              columns: [
                { data: 'content'
                }
              ]
          } );
      } );
```

What output I expect is this.

```
|  Content  |
-------------
   data_v1
   data_v2
   data_v3
```

Note: As long as posible, I don't want to use forloop or any kind of loop. TIA

Any help will be so much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer is from @colin of Datatable.

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var my_data = {
            "contents": [{
                    "data_v1": [{
                        "id": 1
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "data_v2": [{
                        "id": 2
                    }]
                },
                {
                    "data_v3": [{
                        "id": 3
                    }]
                }
            ]
        };
    
    
    
        var table = $('#example').DataTable({
            data: my_data.contents,
            columnDefs: [{
                targets: 0,
                render: function(data, type, row, meta) {
                    return (Object.keys(row)[0]);
    
                }
            }]
        });
    
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table id="example"></table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var myData = {
      "content": [
         {
           "data_v1": [{"id" : 1}]
         },
         {
           "data_v2": [{"id" : 2}]
         },
         {
           "data_v3": [{"id" : 3}]
         }
      ]
   };     
$(document).ready(function() 
                   {
      $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: Object.keys(myData["content"]),
          columns: [
            { title: 'content'
            }
          ]
      });
});
```

Object.keys will return an array of keys from the data provided

Comment: It only return the index.
from 0-2